# Using iterate after installing with Quicklisp

Tags: common-lisp, quicklisp

When I load the "iterate" package using Quicklisp ( `(ql:quickload "iterate")` ), it seems to load fine but none of the functions really work. When I enter `(iterate:iter (for i from 0 to 10) (collect i))`, I get an error saying "The variable I is unbound" and several style warnings saying that COLLECT and FOR are undefined functions and FROM is an undefined variable. The same thing happens if I try to use ITER or ITERATE instead of ITERATE:ITER. I'm using SBCL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "operators" of the clauses also reside in the `iterate` package:

```
(iterate:iter (iterate:for i from 1 to 10) (iterate:collect i))
```

Iterate is a package that is often convenient to `use-package` (or `:use` in the package definition).

Comment: Thanks. I've put in a `:use` at the beginning of my file, but it fails to compile and gives a warning that the package "also exports the following symbols: (preprocess-clause define-clause config2 ...)" and a huge list of symbols. At the beginning of my file, I have `(defpackage :foo (:use :cl :iterate)) (in-package :foo)`. All of the documentation I've read about this seems to indicate this should work, but it doesn't for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a working solution, but I am very curious to find one myself, so, perhaps someone will hep me too :)

```
(defun old-package () (package-name *package*))

(defmacro i++ (&body body)
  (let ((old (package-name *package*))
        (new (package-name (find-package 'iterate))))
    (in-package #.(package-name (find-package 'iterate)))
    (prog1
        `(unwind-protect
              (progn
                (in-package ,new)
                (iter ,@body))
           (in-package ,old))
      (in-package #.(old-package)))))
```

Now, this won't work because the symbols of the body are getting defined in the old (`cl-user` for example) package and then once you try to use them in `iterate` package it all breaks. But there has to be some way... beside replacing all symbols potentially in `iterate` package...

Answer (score 1):

defining it as part of the package with :use is *probably* the best way style-wise,
but I just used

```
(use-package "ITERATE")
```

and it seemed to work just fine.